# Is directly accessing class attribute faster than getting the value via a getter function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have embedded code in python.
I need to access an attribute of an object.

Is doing `objectA.attribute_x` faster than `objectA.get_attribute_x()`?

From OO point of view, using the getter seems the right thing to do. 
But which way is computationally cheaper/faster?

Comment: In Python getters are very rarely the "right thing to do".

Comment: we are too lazy to write function which does only `return objectA.attribute_x`

Comment: Yes, dotted lookups are faster than getters. In Python, getters/setters are usually NOT the right thing to do. This is different from other languages! In other languages, getters and setters are absolutely the right thing to do.

Comment: The nice thing about Python is that you can directly access the attributes as long as you don't need to perform any getter/setter logic. If you do (later on), you can use Python properties which allows you to add logic/validation while still using `objectA.attribute_x` or `objectA.attribute_x = ...`

Comment: Don't spam tags, read the tag-descriptions before adding.

Comment: Use the member-operator (`.`). You can add a getter transparently to the caller lateron with properties, if necessary, if you want without changing the user-code.

Comment: Any time you start to ask "Is X or Y faster", the answer is "Use the very well developed and easy to use timing tools available in python". You can find out quicker than you can type a well-formed question You don't even need to write a loop!

Answer (score 3):

Lets find out! It seems like there is more work with the function call, but lets let `timeit` have a crack at it:

```
from timeit import timeit

class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "bar"
        self.baz = "baz"

    def get_baz(self):
        return self.baz

print(timeit('foo.bar', setup='import __main__;foo=__main__.Foo()', number=10000000))
print(timeit('foo.get_baz()', setup='import __main__;foo=__main__.Foo()', number=10000000))
```

On one run on my computer I got:

```
1.1257502629887313
4.334604475006927
```

Direct attribute lookup is the clear winner.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, `object.attribute` is a simple dictionary key look-up while `object.get_attribute_a` is a dictionary look-up **+** *any overhead of calling the function.*

So yes, the function version is slower and generally not used in the form you're used to; [`properties`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property) are the standard way of managing attributes (and again, the fact that they manage the attribute before returning makes them slower).

Comment: But `property` is a function call.

Comment: @tdelaney yup, it still is slower; my point was that is the standard way of managing attributes instead of java-like `get_attr_x` methods.